# How can i return a value from a global method to the kernel method?

Tags: cuda

I'm calling a global method inside the kernel method and i want to return a value from this method and keep using it in the kernel. I know `__global__` methods are voids, but how can i return the value?

Comment: global method and kernel method are the same thing.  You presumably have a parent kernel and a child kernel.  Establish a pointer to global memory, with an appropriate size allocation for the data you wish to return.  Pass that pointer to the child kernel.  Have the child kernel fill in the pointer/allocated region with the data it wishes to return.  After the child kernel launch is complete, the parent kernel can retrieve the data to be returned using the aforementioned pointer.  Conceptually, this is similar to how data is returned from a host kernel launch, to host code.

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand what you mean.

1. Put the desired variable as an argument of the global function.
2. Use `cudaMemcpy` after the function call, to pass the value from the GPU to the CPU. Ex.: `cudaMemcpy(host_value, device_value, sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);`